# Displaying JSON values from traversed object

Tags: jquery, json

Why won't this display anything in the following example ?

```
$.getJSON('test.json', function (data) {
 $.each(data.glossary, function (index, val){
    var title = val.title, //"example glossary"
    term  = val.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm; //"Standard Generalized Markup Language"
        $('ul#results').append('<li><div class="name">' +this.title+ '</div></li><li><div class="name2">' +term+ '</div></li>');
    });
});
```

I'm having to traverse the object in order to obtain certain values from a complicated nested JSON data file as per below:

```
{
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "Hello!!",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're iterating over `data.glossary`, your first iteration has this:

```
index == "title"
val == "example glossary";
```

`val.title` is simply undefined, but `val.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.GlossTerm` is inaccessible and should be throwing an error in your console.

It doesn't look like you need the `$.each` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You're each function will be called twice, once for title, and once for glosslist. The way you are using it looks like you expect glossary to be an array?